# can i use Class or Method as Enum class's value in Python?

Tags: python, enums

```
from enum import Enum


class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b


class TestEnum(Enum):
    a_name = A


a_class = TestEnum.a_name

a_instance = a_class(b=1)

print(type(a_instance))

### TypeError: 'TestEnum' object is not callable
```

i wanna use Class as Enum's value for specify class using name. but i cannot make instance for Enum value because it is just Enum Class not A Class.

can i make instance like this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is a good idea, but you can get the value of the enum using

```py
a_class = TestEnum.a_name.value
a_instance = a_class(b=1)
print(type(a_instance))
```

Comment: i tried before like that and it worked. but i cannot sure it's good idea as you said. thank you for your reply!